# How to get text from alertbox in spectron-mocha-webdiverio

Tags: electron, webdriver-io, spectron

I am testing my electron app using spectron.
I am trying to get text from alertbox but getting an error.
I want to get the text from alert and if that is expected then accept it.

Test :

```
it('Check alert message', function() {
        return this.app.client
            .waitForExist('#associates', 20000).should.eventually.equal(true)
            .click('#pq-associates')
            .click('#submit-selection')
            .alertText().should.eventually.equal("You have to select any one")
            .should.eventually.exist
    });
```

I am getting the following error

```
no alert open
Error: An attempt was made to operate on a modal dialog when one was not open.
```

But I can see the alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed with the WebDriverio community it is difficult to handle the default alert() function. They suggested to implement my own alert() like function. So using https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2 I implemented my own alert and the test is working fine.

Community discussion : https://gitter.im/webdriverio/webdriverio/archives/2017/10/04

Spectron issue : https://github.com/electron/spectron/issues/23